Introduction to Electronics 6th Current vs. Current Flow

At the brief part author says "To produce a
current flow, the electrons must all move in the
same direction." and at the main part "A current is produced when an electron is forced
from its orbit around an atom." I do not understand, are current and current flow different? I searched that at Google but I did not find answers.

So what is the question about the subject you don't understand? The second statement seems just to be an awkward way of saying that e.g. shining light to a photovoltaic cell pushes the electrons to make them flow/move, and the first statement says a flowing/moving electrons is current. Please understand that this is an introductory course and the statements are a bit hand-wavy simplifications the definitions and how to make electric current. In physics this would not be an accurate model at all, as electrons can't be thouht as balls with a charge, but as waves of energy, or something suitable.

Anakin, I suggest to get and read Matter & Interactions by Chabay and Sherwood. 3rd or 4th edition. It's very accessible and will take you from "knowing nothing much" to having a pretty good handle on things up to and including the beginning of electronic circuits. It's a book on physics. But a very good book with very practical ideas and not too much math along the way.

The OP is asking only one thing here: is current the same as current flow.

@Andyaka Which is nothing more than quibbling. It that's the only question, I'd leave it for those who care about arguing over the number of angels fitting on heads of pins -- or finer details of language use.

@Anakin This is NOT an error in the normal sense - it's just that the writer is so familiar with the subject that they do not realise that failing to use EXACTLY the same terms in every place may be confusing to beginners. This does not mean that the book is bad (it is overall an extremely well regarded book for beginners) but that the editor didn't proof read it in enough depth. || Here the writer has used current and current-flow essentially interchangeably. Others have suggested that he may better have said eg charge-flow but that's a level of detail that he was not intending at this point.

@periblepsis   I think that Andy is correct here - and so are you :-). The OP's question seems to be solely about the terminology used. (Most seem to have missed this). This is effectively a tautology BUT the OP does nopty realise this and that is exactly what he is asking about.

@Andyaka  You are correct. Periblepsis is also correct that this is effectively quibbling BUT that's not a criticism of your comment but of the OP's query. He doesn't know this and is asking for clarification.


I do not understand, are current and current flow different?

I regard it as an error or tautology.
Current is the flow of charge hence current is inherently flowing. Saying "current flow" is either a tautology or a mistake (when the author should have said "charge flow").
It's not a terrible error of course. I bet plenty of us use the term current flow or flow of current just like we use the term rainfall. I mention rainfall because, in a way that's a tautology too. I mean rain usually does falls down!!

We only understand this through models. You need to choose the right level of model for what you are trying to do, otherwise you will get confused.
If you want to build circuits, then please forget about electrons. Think of current as a magical flow of positive charge. That's what I, and 99.99% of practicing electronic engineers do. You can flash LEDs from Ardunios, or design and build continent-wide power distribution networks, using this model.
If you want to understand the physics, perhaps you want to engineer the materials that go inside transistors, then you need to understand rather more than the text you quote is telling you. In metals, the conduction electrons exist in a mobile sea, not localised to any atom at all, needing no threshold to move. In semiconductors, there are bands of energy, and you need to get into quantum mechanics, or at least Fermi levels, to understand what's going on. Most of the electrons are bound to atoms, and a few get promoted to the conduction band and can then move, leaving behind a 'hole' which can also move in response to an electric field, has an effective mass, and can be treated like a quantum mechanical particle itself.
I hate the early teaching of electrons because they are too much, too detailed and confusing for the first application, and not enough for the second.


At the brief part author says "To produce a current flow, the
electrons must all move in the same direction."

There is an error in the book. Electrons flow in the opposite direction of current flow which is also described as the direction of flow of holes. Direction of current is direction of flow of holes.When an electric field or voltage bias is applied, electrons move in the opposite direction of electric field. Each atom, when it loses a electron creates a hole which is positive charge and leaves a gap in the valence shell. This gap is filled by another electron in the lattice of the material and this further creates another gap and the process repeats. The flow of current happens due to the movement of positive charged holes in the gaps of valence shell of atoms. Even though the electrons are the only things moving, it appears that the gap which is a positive charge is moving in the opposite direction of flow of electrons in an electric field which gives a sense of current.This is one way of understanding it.

You are misunderstanding the words you have quoted. The electrons should all move in the same direction (to make a meaningful current) but, that direction isn't implied as being in the same direction of what we regard as conventional current direction.

Current means movement of a scalar quantity in any direction. The electron current moves in the direction of movement of electrons.. The hole current moves in the direction of actual current which is measured

Also - shouldnt we say the electrons should move in the same direction on average. Single electrons will whizz around in the material in "all directions", but with a bias along the field

@MrGerber, these quotes seem like introductory books. What is quoted from the books is correct from a high level abstraction. Thermal noise and other physical phenomena will cause electrons to move randomly, but with a bias towards a direction. However, this can be neglected a lot of the time.

McGerber, Current measured in the conventional sense in modern terminology means flow of positive charge in the opposite direction of flow of electrons. Without any bias, electrons would move randomly and so do the holes. Only during the presence of an electric field i.e by application of a voltage bias, electron movement has a particular direction.

@AmitM, the quote is correct, as it doesn’t mention conventional or physical current direction. It just says electrons must flow in a preferred direction, which is true. Granted, this is from the perspective of a high level abstraction model, ignoring things like electromagnetic wave generation and such.

@JarrodChristman yes. I didn't say the quote was incorrect. Just a bit imprecise.

Jarrod Christman, the author may have meant electron current which is in the direction of flow of electrons. Conventionally, current means direction of positive charge which can be measured with an ammeter or a Galvanometer.  There seemed an error in terminology in the book.

@AmitM Yes, but the quote doesn't say anything about the direction of anything. It's merely saying that the electron flow will be in one direction. The rest of your comment is just telling me back what I already wrote.

McGerber, I added some details in the answer to help understand the movement of electrons in an electric field. For more details, its better to consult a book on semiconductor physics.

The first statement is not completely correct. For a current the mobile electrons, on average, must move in a particular direction. And current flow is redundant.
The second statement is almost nonsense. In a metal conduction electrons are not bound to an atom. In a semiconductor most often electrons arise from doping, and electrons are thermally ionized from a donor atom. And just because they are ionized (which most of them are) doesn't mean they are in motion causing a current.
Please give the NAME(S) of the author(s) of this book. Based on this sample, it should be avoided for any discussion related to physics. I don't know if this is just sloppy writing in one place not essential to the main topic of the book. Or whether other fundamental errors and/ or misconceptions are found elsewhere.
